# Ruby on Rails Capistrano 'Could not locate Gemfile' error when running cap production deploy:initial[]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I'm trying to launch a RoR application and get the following error when running cap production deploy:initial[]

I'm very new to RoR and the setup in general so I cannot provide more detail but am able to answer questions.

```
INFO [ac02eabc] Running ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle install --path /home/deploy/apps/Interface/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet on 178.62.51.103
DEBUG [ac02eabc] Command: cd /home/deploy/apps/Interface/releases/20151022000628 && ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle install --path /home/deploy/apps/Interface/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet
DEBUG [ac02eabc]    Could not locate Gemfile
DEBUG [ac02eabc]    
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host 178.62.51.103: Exception while executing on host 178.62.51.103: bundle exit status: 10
bundle stdout: Could not locate Gemfile
bundle stderr: Nothing written

SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host 178.62.51.103: bundle exit status: 10
bundle stdout: Could not locate Gemfile
bundle stderr: Nothing written

SSHKit::Command::Failed: bundle exit status: 10
bundle stdout: Could not locate Gemfile
bundle stderr: Nothing written

Tasks: TOP => deploy:initial
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing on host 178.62.51.103: Exception while executing on host 178.62.51.103: bundle exit status: 10
bundle stdout: Could not locate Gemfile
bundle stderr: Nothing written
jordan@Jordans-MacBook-Air:~/revolvr/Interface$
```

The way my repo is set up is I hate the repo, then two sub directories. One containing the RoR files and the other some python code. When I set up deploy.rb the github link only points to the repository, not the corresponding folder with the RoR files and the Gemfile... could this be why it is not working?

Answer (score 1):

First check the Gemfile is present in server or not.

If present, then specify the location in your configuration file by adding below code.

> `set :bundle_gemfile,  "rails_code/Gemfile"`